# Counting rows from a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

How could I count rows from a SELECT query as a value?
Such as

```
SELECT FUCNTIONIMLOOKINGFOR(SELECT * FROM anothertable) AS count FROM table;
```

So that count is an integer of how many rows the subquery `SELECT * FROM anothertable` returns.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT p.PostPID, p.PostUID, p.PostText, p.PostTime, u.UserUID, u.UserName, u.UserImage, u.UserRep,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(f.FlagTime)
            FROM Flags as f 
                JOIN Posts as p 
                ON p.PostPID = f.FlagPID
    ) as PostFlags
    FROM Posts AS p
        JOIN Users AS u
        ON p.PostUID = u.UserUID
    ORDER BY PostTime DESC
    LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: @Charlie - not sure if you're getting an error, but are you missing a comma before the ( SELECT ... ) as PostFlags?

Comment: @Charlie - I'm not sure what the 'v' in v.FlagTime is referring to, you don't have any join labeled with a v, what about f.FlagTime?

Comment: @Charlie - so everything fixed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM aTable ) as count FROM table
```

I assume your example is a truncated version of your actual query, so perhaps you should post what you are after to get a, possibly, more optimal query.

**EDIT**

Working directly from my brain, something like this should be more optimal.

```
SELECT p.PostPID, p.PostUID, p.PostText, p.PostTime, u.UserUID, u.UserName, u.UserImage, u.UserRep, COUNT(v.FlagTime) as postFlags
    FROM Flags as f 
    JOIN Posts as p ON p.PostPID = f.FlagPID
    JOIN Users AS u ON p.PostUID = u.UserUID
LIMIT 0, 30
GROUP BY p.PostPID
ORDER BY PostTime DESC
```

Comment: If not all posts have flags this would exclude those that do not. If that is the case then do `from posts left join Flags...`

Answer (score 11):

You can say

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anothertable
```

which will return a numeric value, which you can use in another query, such as in the select list of another query, or as a condition in another query.

```
SELECT someVariable FROM table
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anotherTable) > 5
```

OR

```
SELECT someVariable, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anotherTable) as count FROM table
```

Comment: I updated my post. But the subquery seems to be executed without the join.