# MySQL Query - How to check second table record exist or not?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am using cakephp v.3.2. Now I am facing some problem my query. Please check below my json record -

```
{
    "id": 22,
    "title": "",
    "description": "vfdvfdvffd",
    "type": 0,
    "allow_comment": 0,
    "owner_id": 35,
    "created": "2016-04-11T12:02:29+0000",
    "status": 1,
    "post_images": []
 },
```

I have two tables one is `posts` and another is `post_images` I am using hasmany. But I want to show all the records which is no post_images.

I am trying following code but not working. Please see my code -

```
$get_post_list_for_photo_tab = $this->Posts->find('all')
           ->where([
                  'Posts.owner_id' =>$query_for_school_admin['id'],
                  'post_images !='=>''])
           ->contain(['PostImages'])
           ->order(['created' => 'DESC'])->toArray();
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibile solutions:

- [Implement a counter cache](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html) and filter by that fields value
- [Use a sub query](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#subqueries) to do the count and filter by the aliased field that contains the result of the subquery. See [Counting rows from a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354273/counting-rows-from-a-subquery)